# WSS server/client/jetty example

Tags: websocket, embedded-jetty

WebSocket noob...

Anyone have a link to a complete jetty 11/12 example with working secure websocket server/client?

I've followed many separate server examples and client examples but there's always an issue whether its an SSL handshake or frame length error or close no_error EoFException. None of them have a complete example, including all dependencies with versions.

Edit:
For the down voters...
I realise this a broad question. Feel free point me to a better forum to ask this type of question. I figured asking for a eg. link to a working github project would be better than spamming SO with questions every time I hit a problem with broken examples.

Comment: A better forum would be to ask a "Question" at https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues

Answer (score -1):

This is an overly broad question.

See https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded

Look at either of the Jetty 12 sub-projects

- `ee10-websocket-jakarta-api`
- `ee10-websocket-jetty-api`

These contain the examples you are looking for.

In short, you'll need for the server side ...

- `ServerConnector` configured to support whatever "secure" connection you want (https / wss / http1 / http2 / http3 / etc)
- A context that can receive the request.
- The context configured to accept WebSocket upgrades.
- The websocket upgrade configured (with a type of `WebSocketCreator` depending on chosen technology / APIs) that specifies what path should respond with what websocket endpoint.

For the client side you'll need ...

- a `WebSocketClient` (of the type appropriate for your chosen websocket technology / API).
- a declared WebSocket endpoint that the client uses to receive websocket frames/messages/ping/pong
- use the `WebSocketClient` to establish the Request parameters.
- connect with the Request object and the websocket endpoint.
- wait for connect (usually seen as a `CompletableFuture.get()`)

Comment: That's my point. Yet another server example without a working client example.

Comment: I tossed up some WebSocket client code as unit tests on those projects for you.